# R: using package by unzipping it instead of installing it

Tags: r, package

I am trying to use a package which can not run at such in window Rgui. The website of the package suggests for unzip and use the function

http://mouse.cs.ucla.edu/emma/install.html

But I did not way to find where I can find the function that I can enter in my R console and use it.

Help appreciated

EDITS:

RGUi that comes with windows distribution

Packaged useed is: emma, can be downloaded from the above website

Comment: If you download the tar.gz file and unpack it, you'll see a folder called 'R'. That folder contains two .R files that you can call into R using source("pathtoRfile.R"). That should work for you in the meantime

Comment: I used *.zip as I am using windows, I do not have experience on tar.gz files, thank you for the help

Comment: my R folder has three files not any with R extension( *.R), but emma, emma.rdb, emma.rdx

Comment: I don't have a windows machine to test on, but I think I've unpacked tar.gz files on Windows using a free program called 7-zip before. In there, the R folder for sure contains .R files

Comment: If you want to see the R code in simple text files, you **must** download the _Package source_, which has a `.tar.gz` suffix.  As @timriffe said, you can install `7-zip` for free, and use it to unpack the 'tarball'. If you're getting this package from CRAN, the file with a `.zip` suffix is a compiled _Windows binary_, which contains the three files you described.

Comment: Digging stuff out from the package source is certainly the most practical way to go.  If you want to use the `.rdb` and `.rdx` files it *might* be possible, but you would have to read and understand http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Lazy-loading and `?lazyLoad` first ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the all-R, mouse-free version (I was almost there Roman!):

```
    download.file("http://mouse.cs.ucla.edu/emma/emma_1.1.2.tar.gz",
        destfile=paste(getwd(),"/emma/emma_1.1.2.tar.gz",sep=""))
    untar(paste(getwd(),"/emma/emma_1.1.2.tar.gz",sep=""), compressed = "gzip")
    source(paste(getwd(),"/emma/R/emma.R",sep=""))
```

wherein a new directory (emma/) will be created in your present working directory.

Comment: works thanks....I think what is Roman suggested is similar but I do not know but did not worked for me...may be my computer is killing the torball in the dowload process or ? ...

Comment: @John, what version of R are you running?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the .tar.gz file and use `untar` function. I've moved the file in question to my Q drive in folder emma and ran the following command. The result was extracted to a folder called emma under my working directory.

```
untar("q:/emma/emma_1.1.2.tar.gz", compressed = "gzip")
```

After you've done that, you can `source` the .R files (see comments under your question).

Comment: I followed the procedure but no luck. No error message in RGui console.....it did nothing...I tried to download and tried again and agin...but do not work..may be the file is currpted or something I am not aware of..