# R alternative to install.packages() function

Tags: r, macos

Is there any documentation on manually installing a package in a user library when the `R.home()` path is locked down and incomplete (no `etc`, no `bin`, just `library`?) The system does NOT support shelling out to execute `R CMD`, which I believe standard R does.

I would like to build existing source packages (from CRAN) and install into a user library directory, so that I can use the `library()` function and get all the usual namespace and *.Rdx and *.Rdb files.

At the moment, I'm plodding through `install.packages`, `tools::.build_package`, and `tools:::.install.packages` source, using a standard MacOS R and the r source. Hopefully this has been documented in a more user-friendly fashion and my google searches have missed it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting a path manually with `.libPaths("/new/path", .libPaths())`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905628/r-using-package-by-unzipping-it-instead-of-installing-it

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have. The problem is that R.home directory is locked and does not include the scripts in `etc`, `bin`, etc. which R normally uses to build or install packages. That directory is not writable.

Comment: The possible dup you suggested  seems to assume the a precompiled binary is available (unless the `*.Rdb` and `*.Rdx` are portable) I am using a Unix derivative. If the files are portable then I can use a Mac binary and simply change the Built: line in the description to reflect the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a different `install.packages` method, rather you only need to specify a writable location for storing packages and give it precedence over the system default one.  A simple way to accomplish this is to set an `R_LIBS` environment variable.  For instance, in my `.bashrc` I have

```
export R_LIBS='/home/username/.local/lib/R-3.3.3'
```

Then, by default, all packages are installed here. Further, packages installed both here and the system-wide location will give priority to the ones here when loading.

You can verify that the location is being used by checking `.libPaths()` in your R session.

Comment: Thank you, but I am working with a sandboxed embedded version of R (no bash, no .bashrc, no environment variables) so I can't set those.  I have prepended a writeable directory onto the .libPaths. I then install the package on my Mac, tar and zip it and send to the embedded device. That works for packages that don't require compilation.

Comment: However, I have to manage the dependency chain myself. Thanks goodness for the minicran package!